# Ignoring apostrophe in MySQL full-text-search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a song title in my `music` table which is: `o'najr`

I would like to show that result if user type:

```
1. o'najr
2. onajr
3. o najr
```

and the result should be the same.

`1. and 3. are working but 2. is not.`

```
$search_value = $db->mysqli->real_escape_string("onajr");
$search_value = str_replace(" ", " +", $search_value);

$query = "
    select * from `music` 
    where (
        match(`title`, `artist`) against (replace('$search_value', '\'', '') IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
        or
        match(`title`, `artist`) against (replace('$search_value', '\'', ' ') IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
        or 
        match(`title`, `artist`) against ('$search_value')
        )
";
```

Comment: have you considered SOUNDEX?

Comment: Yes but I'm trying to find another way.

Comment: the problem is if it exists as o'najr then it is indexed as two separate words. To match, you'd have to break the search to have 2 words. Best would be to add a 'tags' field to your table that had a list of alternate spellings for each artist.